# ngFor to iterate an array of objects and count the length of an array property

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ngfor, angular-template

I'm doing a web application in Angular 6. I receives an array of objects from Firebase and I'm trying to show the details to the user using `ngFor`. My array of objects is like this:

```
export interface Competition {
  createdAt: Date;
  sessions: Session[];
}

export interface Session {
  date: Date;
  program: Program[];
  events: Event[];
}

export interface Program {
  name: string;
}

export interface Event {
  name: string;
}
```

Inside the template I am doing:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let competition of competitions; index as i">
   <h3>{{competition.name}}</h3>
   {{competition.sessions[i].program.length}}
   {{competition.sessions[i].events.length}}
</ng-container>
```

> read property 'program' of undefined, read property 'events' of
>   undefined

I have tried:

```
{{competition[i].sessions[i].program.length}}
{{competition.sessions[i].program.length}}
{{competition[i].sessions[i].program[i].length}}
```

My goal is to show the length of `program` and `events`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You iterate over `competitions` array but try to get `competition.sessions[i]`.
You need something like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let competition of competitions; index as i">
   <h3>{{competition.name}}</h3>
   <div *ngFor="let session of competition.sessions">
      {{session.program.length}}
      {{session.events.length}}
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

If you want to get the total number of sessions and event for a competition, you should count them in your ts file

```
this.competitionResults = this.competitions
   .map(competition => competition.sessions
       .reduce((res, session) => 
           ({
                programLength: res.programLength + session.program.length, 
                eventLength: res.eventLength + session.events.length,
           }), {
                programLength: 0, 
                eventLength: 0,
           }))
   )
```

And HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let competitionResult of competitionResults">
   {{ competitionResult.programLength }}
   {{ competitionResult.eventLength}}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me. I have tried your solution and it works but, it prints a session twice. I mean, if a session has two program, it prints that number twice, first 1, then 2, and so on. Seems to me a normal thing because of `ngFor`, there would be a way to just print the total `length` of the array?

Comment: Hi. This code will show you programs' and events' numbers for every session of every competition. `.length` shows the total length of an array. If you want to get a total number of events in the whole competition you should do it via ts: `competition.sessions.reduce((res, session) => ({programLength: res.programLength + session.program.length, eventLength: res.eventLength + session.events.length}), {programLength: 0, eventLength: 0})` or something like this and use this object in your template.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. One more question, I didn't know about `reduce()`, I have tried it in my class but, `sessions`, according to the IDE, does not exist, which is false. I have globally `competitions: Competition[];`. Can you help me a little bit to make it work? I appreciate it.

Comment: @RRGT19 you just can map through your competition and combine all lengths of events and programs for every session in every competition. I updated reply with the final code. Check it out.

Comment: The last `ngFor` that you added, keeps printing both values over and over again until the last value is reached. I have used the `i` variable of `let competition of competitions; index as i` and then I did in the template `{{competitionResults[i].programLength}}` and it's working. I don't know if this is the best solution anyway.

Comment: Check it again. It should work. `competitionResults` should have `{programLength: number, eventLength: number}[]` interface. In the end, you will have two numbers for every competition. If you want to get total numbers for all competitions you can use `reduce` function on `competitionResults`.

Comment: Got it. One last question, since I'm using an interface, do I need to have both properties as `0` inside the `reduce` function as you have right now in your answer? It's mandatory? Your function works right now but, due to my low knowledge about these functions, seems a little overwhelming for me.

Comment: You can read about reduce [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). The first argument is a callback. The second argument is the initial value. The callback will be called for every item of the array. And `res` for the first call will be the initial value. And if your array is empty you will get the initial value as the result of `reduce` function. You can write reduce function without an initial value. But it will be more difficult to write and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Change your definitions to define string arrays directly:

```
export interface Session {
  date: Date;
  program: string[];
  events: string[];
}
```